# How to generate a unique numeric ID in SQL Server (not using identity)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier, unique-id

I need a unique number id for my table. Usually I would use Identity in Sql Server, but there is a catch to my use case. I would like to know the id before the row is created (to be able to reference it in other records in memory, before committing everything to the database).

I don't know if it's possible to achieve with Identity, but I could not figure that out.

So my next best guess is that I need a table that will store one value and keep incrementing it and returning me a new value for the id. Access would have to be locked so that no two operations can get the same value.

I am thinking of using e.g. `sp_getapplock @Resource = 'MyUniqueId'` to prevent same number from being returned to a caller. Perhaps I can use ordinary locking in transactions for that as well.

Is there any better approach to the problem?

Comment: You can use SEQUENCE to retrieve a new unique value from the server. You don't need explicit locks

Comment: yes, looks like it's exactly what I need, does it guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: It does - even rolling back a transaction won't reset a SEQUENCE. On the other hand, if you explicitly reset it it will start producing the same values again. That's no different than reseeding an IDENTITY

Comment: I hope I can avoid resetting it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15) object that produces incrementing values. A SEQUENCE can be used independently or as a default value for one or more tables.

You can create a sequence with `CREATE SEQUENCE` :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Audit.EventCounter  
    AS int  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

You can retrieve the next value atomically with `NEXT VALUE FOR` and use it in multiple statements eg :

```
DECLARE @NextID int ;  
SET @NextID = NEXT VALUE FOR Audit.EventCounter;
```

Rolling back a transaction doesn't affect a SEQUENCE. From the docs:

> Sequence numbers are generated outside the scope of the current transaction. They are consumed whether the transaction using the sequence number is committed or rolled back.

You can use `NEXT VALUE FOR` as a default in multiple tables. In the documentation example, three different types of event table use the same SEQUENCE allowing all events to get unique numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE Audit.ProcessEvents  
(  
    EventID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
        DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Audit.EventCounter),  
    EventTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),  
    EventCode nvarchar(5) NOT NULL,  
    Description nvarchar(300) NULL  
) ;  
GO  
  
CREATE TABLE Audit.ErrorEvents  
(  
    EventID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
        DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Audit.EventCounter),  
    EventTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),  
    EquipmentID int NULL,  
    ErrorNumber int NOT NULL,  
    EventDesc nvarchar(256) NULL  
) ;  
GO  
  
CREATE TABLE Audit.StartStopEvents  
(  
    EventID int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  
        DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR Audit.EventCounter),  
    EventTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),  
    EquipmentID int NOT NULL,  
    StartOrStop bit NOT NULL  
) ;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to use a UUID to represent each unique record.  Should you want to generate the UUID within SQL Server, you could use the `NEWID()` function (see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information).  If this value would be generated from your application code, you could convert it to `uniqueidentifier` type within SQL Server using `CONVERT`.

For reference, a UUID is a 16 byte unique identifier.  It is *extremely* unlikely that your application or SQL Server would ever generate the same UUID more than once.  They look like this:

```
773c1570-1076-4e19-b728-6d7b0b20895a
```

Comment: That would result in index fragmentation quite quickly. At the very least one should use `NEWSEQUENTIALID` or the equivalent on the client

Comment: Yes, I have thought about using UUID, but as far as I know using UUID as primary key would make all the future joins/searches slower compared to a number

Answer (score 0):

If you want a behaviour that matches the one of an `IDENTITY` column, try:

`CREATE SEQUENCE mydb.dbo.mysequence;`

And then, repeatedly:

`SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR mysequence;`

And , if you want to play some more, see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

happy playing ...